# Update Icon on a Marker with a Object literal

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Since MarkerImage is gone I constantly have this problem with the update of Icon for a Marker.

Fist call to Marker.setIcon({url: "icon url", anchor: ....}) works ok, but after when I try to make setIcon on the same marker with a same Object literal it throws this exception in the debugger:

```
<exception>: Af
message: "not a string"
name: "InvalidValueError"
stack: "Error↵ at Error (native)↵ at new Af (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/10/intl/de_ALL/main.js:26:682)↵ at Bf (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/10/intl/de_ALL/main.js:26:795)↵ at http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/10/intl/de_ALL/main.js:28:60↵ at http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/10/intl/de_ALL/main.js:28:181↵ at http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/10/intl/de_ALL/main.js:28:401↵ at Zh.setIcon (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/10/intl/de_ALL/main.js:31:1423)↵ at $setIcon_6 (0.js:59576:15)↵ at $update_10 (0.js:98065:3)↵ at $liveTimerFireEvent (0.js:113687:7)"
__proto__: c
c: Object
anchor: U
origin: U
size: W
url: "resources/image.png"
__proto__: Object
this: undefined
```

As its obvious in the exception, I use version 21/10
Dose someone had something similar as a problem? 
I test it shortly with a String instead of a Object for a Icon, it dose work like this...

Because people down vote my question before I even had a chance to say its not plain js...here un extracted example...

```js
    /*
     * declare map as a global variable
     */
    var map;

    /*
     * use google maps api built-in mechanism to attach dom events
     */
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

      /*
       * create map
       */
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      /*
       * create infowindow (which will be used by markers)
       */
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      /*
       * marker creater function (acts as a closure for html parameter)
       */
      function createMarker(options, html) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(options);
        if (html) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(options.map, this);
          });
        }
        return marker;
      }

      /*
       * add markers to map
       */
      var marker0 = createMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
        map: map,
        icon: { url :  "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png" }
      }, "<h1>Marker 0</h1><p>This is the home marker.</p>");

      var marker1 = createMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.818038, -117.928492),
        map: map
      }, "<h1>Marker 1</h1><p>This is marker 1</p>");

      var marker2 = createMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.803333, -117.915278),
        map: map
      }, "<h1>Marker 2</h1><p>This is marker 2</p>");
        
        setInterval(function(){ marker0.setIcon({ url :  "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png" }); alert("called");}, 3000);
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_div" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Post your javascript code that demonstrates what you're doing

Comment: Well I was a bit clear in the question which states : 
Dose someone else had some similar problem on updating a Marker icon with a Icon object? 

I cannot post the code because I use a gwt wrapper, and is a part of a very huge application. But the thing is the code worked perfectly before google did the change from MarkerImage to Icon(Plain js object), now its also working but not 100% as expected. 

I dont do anything special inside. 
Just like I said in the post create marker and try to update the Icon with a object, I added now also a plan js code which generates the same exception...

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/duncancumming/86oj3ppq/  Is your problem where you create `marker0` or where you update it with `marker0.setIcon` ?

Comment: Open it with chrome, then open the debugger end enable the check box "pause on caught exceptions". When marker0.setIcon update is called ull get the exception, and chrome will pause. Under the 'Scope section' ull see the exception I have posted ubove.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it runs just fine with setIcon({url: "green-marker..."}). I used v3.exp, and the embedded code snippet runner thing works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying your icon like:

```
marker0.setIcon({ url :  "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png" });
```

Just use the URL directly, not as a property of a structure that you pass to setIcon.  This worked for me without throwing errors:

```
marker0.setIcon("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_GZzKwf6g1o8/S6xwK6CSghI/AAAAAAAAA98/_iA3r4Ehclk/s1600/marker-green.png");
```

Comment: Well I wrote that in the post. "with a String instead of a Object for a Icon, it dose work"(meaning when url of the Icon is set as a string). 

But its clearly a bug in the Maps api. [link]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.20/reference#Icon  has other options to set also e.g Anchor, ScaledSize etc which Im using it...